# Google Sheets API v4 and reading a hyperlink field

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, google-sheets

I've been trying to find documentation for this within the Sheets API and I can't seem to do it.

Let's say I have a spreadsheet containing hyperlinks formatted as HTML hyperlinks, with links and descriptive text, as in the example below:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rdZGPmFdAJw14GCtuibzwc5BJ3rxy1l81PLJVPTFz4k/edit#gid=0

I figured out how to read the spreadsheet and extract the data using the API. What I can't figure out is how to extract both the text and the hyperlink from the link field. I can get the text, but not the hyperlink.

My code is below, with the appropriate security-associated stuff removed/altered:

```
Dim Scopes As String() = {SheetsService.Scope.Spreadsheets} ' I may want to read/write sometimes, hence the scope.
Dim ApplicationName As String = "My App Name"
    Dim ServiceAccountEmail As String = "email@example.com"
    Dim certificate = New X509Certificate2("my-file.p12", "privatekeygoeshere", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable)
    Dim credential As New ServiceAccountCredential(New ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(ServiceAccountEmail) With {
            .Scopes = Scopes
    }.FromCertificate(certificate))
    Dim service = New SheetsService(New BaseClientService.Initializer() With {
      .ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
      .HttpClientInitializer = credential
     })
    Dim spreadsheetId As String = "1rdZGPmFdAJw14GCtuibzwc5BJ3rxy1l81PLJVPTFz4k"
    Dim Range As String = "Links!A2:A100000"
    Dim Sheetrequest As SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.GetRequest = service.Spreadsheets.Values.[Get](spreadsheetId, Range)
    Dim Sheetresponse As ValueRange = Sheetrequest.Execute()
    Dim values As IList(Of IList(Of Object)) = Sheetresponse.Values ' everything is good up to here.
    For Each row As IList(Of Object) In values
        Response.Write(row(0) & "<br />") ' row(0) contains the link...this is what I probably need to format.
    Next
```

Comment: Your code is VBA. AFAIK, Sheets doesn't support VBA. How does your code work?

Comment: It's VB.net. It simply opens up the certificate, retrieves the spreadsheet, and extracts the values.